# libgdx snake logic explained

Tags: libgdx, game-loop

This is the code from a book I am reading. It is just a snake game. you can paste this code into editor and change 3 texture files to what you have on computer. The code works fine and this is probably really stupid, but I am unable to make the connection between snakeBody parts and their position. How exactly does the body of the snake(not the head) knows where it should go after the head of the snake changes position? Can you elaborate on this? Thank you

// class 1/2:

```
 public class MyGdxGame extends Game {


@Override
public void create () {
setScreen(new GameScreen());
}
```

}
class 2/2:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ScreenAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;

import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter{
    private static final float MOVE_TIME = 0.5F;
    private static final int SNAKE_MOVEMENT = 32;

    private static final int RIGHT = 0;
    private static final int LEFT = 1;
    private static final int UP = 2;
    private static final int DOWN = 3;

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture snakeHead;
    private Texture snakeBody;
    private Texture apple;

    private boolean appleAvailable = false;
    private int appleX, appleY;

    private float timer = MOVE_TIME;
    private int snakeX = 0, snakeY = 0;
    private int snakeXBeforeUpdate = 0, snakeYBeforeUpdate = 0;

    private int snakeDirection = RIGHT;

    private Array<BodyPart> bodyParts = new Array<BodyPart>();

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        snakeHead = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("snakehead.png"));
        snakeBody = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("snakeBody.png"));
        apple = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("apple.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);
        queryInput();
        timer -= delta;
        if (timer <= 0) {
            timer = MOVE_TIME;
            moveSnake();
            checkForOutOfBounds();
            updateBodyPartsPosition();
        }
        checkAppleCollision();
        checkAndPlaceApple();
        clearScreen();
        draw();
    }

    private void queryInput() {
        boolean lPressed = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT);
        boolean rPressed = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT);
        boolean uPressed = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP);
        boolean dPressed = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN);

        if (lPressed) snakeDirection = LEFT;
        if (rPressed) snakeDirection = RIGHT;
        if (uPressed) snakeDirection = UP;
        if (dPressed) snakeDirection = DOWN;
    }

    private void moveSnake() {
        snakeXBeforeUpdate = snakeX;
        snakeYBeforeUpdate = snakeY;
        switch (snakeDirection) {
            case RIGHT: {
                snakeX += SNAKE_MOVEMENT;
                return;
            }
            case LEFT: {
                snakeX -= SNAKE_MOVEMENT;
                return;
            }
            case UP: {
                snakeY += SNAKE_MOVEMENT;
                return;
            }
            case DOWN: {
                snakeY -= SNAKE_MOVEMENT;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkForOutOfBounds() {
        if (snakeX >= Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) {
            snakeX = 0;
        }
        if (snakeX < 0) {
            snakeX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - SNAKE_MOVEMENT;
        }
        if (snakeY >= Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) {
            snakeY = 0;
        }
        if (snakeY < 0) {
            snakeY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - SNAKE_MOVEMENT;
        }
    }

    private void updateBodyPartsPosition() {
        if (bodyParts.size > 0) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = bodyParts.removeIndex(0);
            bodyPart.updateBodyPosition(snakeXBeforeUpdate, snakeYBeforeUpdate);
            bodyParts.add(bodyPart);
        }
    }

    private void checkAndPlaceApple() {
        if (!appleAvailable) {
            do {
                appleX = MathUtils.random(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / SNAKE_MOVEMENT - 1) * SNAKE_MOVEMENT;
                appleY = MathUtils.random(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / SNAKE_MOVEMENT - 1) * SNAKE_MOVEMENT;
                appleAvailable = true;
            } while (appleX == snakeX && appleY == snakeY);
        }
    }

    private void checkAppleCollision() {
        if (appleAvailable && appleX == snakeX && appleY == snakeY) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = new BodyPart(snakeBody);
            bodyPart.updateBodyPosition(snakeX, snakeY);
            bodyParts.insert(0,bodyPart);
            appleAvailable = false;
        }
    }

    private void clearScreen() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Color.BLACK.r, Color.BLACK.g, Color.BLACK.b, Color.BLACK.a);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    private void draw() {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(snakeHead, snakeX, snakeY);
        for (BodyPart bodyPart : bodyParts) {
            bodyPart.draw(batch);
        }
        if (appleAvailable) {
            batch.draw(apple, appleX, appleY);
        }
        batch.end();
    }

    private class BodyPart {

        private int x, y;
        private Texture texture;

        public BodyPart(Texture texture) {
            this.texture = texture;
        }

        public void updateBodyPosition(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void draw(Batch batch) {
            if (!(x == snakeX && y == snakeY)) batch.draw(texture, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it moves the head in moveSnake(), making sure to keep track of where the head was before the move. Then in updateBodyPartsPosition() it puts the last piece of the body where the head was just moved from.

Comment: Yees. That's it. One minor question. In the last line of code, mainly in the draw metod, bodyParts are drawn after the head position is. however, I think that  the snakeBody appears below the snakehead, and therefore it is not visible until the snake moves forward. Why are they drawn below the snakehead?

Comment: Like you said, the body parts would be drawn on top of the head if they overlap. I'm not sure what you're seeing without a picture.